# SPA only using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, using

I want to make a small SPA application only using knockout. I don't want to use any other technology. Just pure knockout. The example given at Knockout website is not very clear --> (http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/mail?tutorial=webmail).

I am stuck in how to make that external file (/mail) from where the data is loaded.what will be the structure of that file. Is that a JSON file? and how to get data from that file. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Even if you want only knockout on the client side, you will likely need "something" from the server side to push the data (and probably save the data in DB or files), like this mail JSON object

Comment: knockout is not a full SPA framework but rather a library handling views. You still need something to handle routing etc.

Comment: @AdamWolski Knockout can very well handle SPA. Routing is not necessary for a SPA

Comment: @GôTô What do you mean routing is not necessary for SPA? How do you handle routes with javascript then ?

Comment: @AdamWolski an SPA can be single view. Besides you can load dynamically view parts without navigating to a new route. It depends on the complexity of your application

Comment: @GôTô one can argue with that. If it is a single view I would not call that "an application" but a single page, simply. Also, building any app slightly more complex than single view without routing seems quite silly. I don't see any practical application but maybe you can enlighten me

Comment: @AdamWolski there are single purpose applications... Take a websearch engine. Do you need more than 1 view? We don't know what application OP wants to build (except that it is a small SPA). Yes if you have multiple views routing will make it simpler and you will likely use it. Anyway, we are not really helping with the question

Comment: @GôTô you need routing even in one view application, can u image search engine without the possibility to share url?

Comment: @AdamWolski no need for routing to manage URL...

Comment: @GôTô good luck with managing URL purely with html5 history api. eot.

Comment: The external data isn't a file it's an API call. You can go to http://learn.knockoutjs.com/mail?folder=Inbox and see that the server is returning a javascript object. That path could be pointing to an asp.net api controller, or a node.js server or a hundred other things, but it's probably not a file.

Comment: The example itself is already using something other than knockout. You can see in the code that it's using Sammy.js for the routing, so you might want to define what you mean by "only using knockout" because that's a pretty grey area.

Comment: Is it possible to build a SPA only using knockout ? without any dependencies?  @Jason Spake

Comment: if that is an API call how would i implement that? i just want to make simple SPA for my better understanding.Help me in that.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you imposing this restriction to help yourself learn knockout without any distractions?

Comment: You can say this.But my aim is to create a small and simple SPA using knockout,data should be fetched from an external file. Can this be done using templates.?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to load data from an external file using knockout. That's not the point of knockout and not something it -should- do. You'll have to use another library like require.js to load files unless you are also running a web-server that can return the file from an api call, but that's still not "knockout only".

Comment: i have created a simple SPA kind of thing using templates in knockout. but still no external data. @JasonSpake